# Convergence in distribution of mean of i.i.d standard normal RV

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, weak-convergence

Given a sequence of i.i.d standard normal random variables, ${X_n}$, define $F_n(X)$ as the CDF of the mean of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$. What is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_n(X).$

This problem is presented in the textbook before the central limit theorem and so I'm not sure what tools to approach it with. Any hints?

Comment: We can see that the distribution is $N(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n})$. Now you can take the limit of the CDF of this distribution as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: How do you get that the mean follows a normal distribution with those parameters?

Comment: suppose $X \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$, $Y \sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$, then $X+Y \sim N(\mu_1+\mu_2, \sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)$

Also $cX \sim N(c\mu_1, c^2 \sigma_1^2)$. So we use this to work out mean and variance of $\sum \frac{X_i}{n}$

Comment: Use what you know about the sum of independent normal distributions. You should be able to find the CDF of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$. Then take the limit.

Comment: Is the answer supposed to be a closed form formula, because I'm not too sure how to work with the cdf of a normal random variable

Comment: You can transform it into a standard normal distribution and take the limit in $n$

Comment: Intuitively, it seems to converge to the degenerate random variable at the mean

Comment: Since the variance tends to 0, we must have that the distribution tends to a constant function at $\mu$, thus the distribution is as follows: $F(x) = 0$ if $x\lt \mu$ and 1 otherwise?

Comment: the pointwise limit is $F_n(x) \to \Phi(\mu)$

Comment: Where $\Phi$ denotes the standard normal?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: Perhaps this chain of comments is getting a bit long, but I'm not sure I follow how you achieve this result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $n$, the mean of $n$ i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ variables is $\sim N(0,1/n)$, which can be derived from basic properties of Gaussians - no need of CLT for this.

So intuitively in the limit, the mean becomes constant $0$.  Let $Y$ denote this constant r.v. (i.e. $Y=0$ surely) and $Y$ would have this CDF:

$$F_Y(x) = 0, 1 ~~~~\text{depending on}~~~ x < 0, \ge 0 ~~~~\text{respectively}$$

However, there is (I think) a technicality.  The question is not asking for $F_Y$.  Instead it asks for the limit of $F_n(x)$, and if you look at the formula for CDF of Gaussians, you can see that $F_n(0) = 1/2$  for all $n$.  So the limit must be the same way.  I.e. I think the question is asking for the limit of a sequence of CDF functions $F_n$, and the limit is:

$$F_\infty(x) = 0, \frac12,1 ~~~~\text{depending on}~~~ x < 0, = 0, > 0 ~~~~\text{respectively}$$

Note that $F_\infty(x)$ is not a proper CDF any more, because it is not right-continuous at $x=0$.  However, in my interpretation of the wording of the question, it is asking for the limit of a sequence of functions $F_n$, each of which is a CDF, but it does not care that the limit itself is not a CDF.

Just my interpretation.  :)